# method not found installing HttpClientPlugin for ktor for HttpClient

Tags: java, kotlin, ktor

i have calss in my ktor server on Client module that i initialize http client inside that class as follow :

```
object KtorClient {

private val serializeJson = Json {
    prettyPrint = true
    isLenient = true
    ignoreUnknownKeys = true
}

val httpClient = HttpClient {
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json(json = serializeJson)
    }

    install(HttpRequestRetry) {
        //function enables retrying a request if a 5xx response is received from a server and specifies the number of retries.
        retryOnServerErrors(5)
        //specifies an exponential delay between retries, which is calculated using the Exponential backoff algorithm.
        exponentialDelay()
        //If you want to add some additional params in header
        modifyRequest { request ->
            request.headers.append("x-retry-count", 2.toString())
        }
    }

    //If you want to change user agent
    install(UserAgent) {
        agent = "Ktor"
    }

    install(DefaultRequest) {
        headers.appendIfNameAbsent("X-custom-header", "Some Value")
        contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
    }

    ResponseObserver {
        val timeDifference = it.responseTime.timestamp - it.requestTime.timestamp
        val protocolVersion = it.version
    }
}
```

}

when i run server and server and running code reaches to this part :

```
install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json(json = serializeJson)
    }
```

i get this error :
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void io.ktor.client.HttpClientConfig.install(io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpClientPlugin, kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1)'

this is my build.gradle file dependencies part for client module :

```
dependencies {
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-jvm:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktor_version")
testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:1.9.20")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:2.3.0")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:1.3.1")
implementation("com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:1.16.0")
implementation("com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev20220815-2.0.0")
```

}

It's three days im struggling with this i have changed versions of dependencies for many times for ktor itself and content negotiation and http alient finally i have this version for all of dependencies related to this part

```
ktor_version=2.3.6
```

and no result every time im running server on part of initializing client and install(ContentNegotiation)
i get mentioned error. any help will be appritiated.

Comment: Can you please double-check that you have only one version of Ktor in your dependencies? Those kinds of errors occur when there are multiple versions of Ktor in the classpath.

Comment: you are right my friend. i checked that my ktor version on my other module was 1.6.4 and in recent module was 2.3.6. I had to update my main module to 2.3.6 and change bunch of dependencies and imports to upgrade to ktor 2.3.6 . after that and cleaning and building project preoblem were gone. thank you